# Package 'perforce-swarm' has no installation candidate

Tags: 14.04, apt

Disclaimer: I have relatively little experience with Linux

I am attempting to install perforce swarm following this guide: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/swarm/setup.packages.html following the steps for Debian. Got through the first two steps with no errors, looked like they were doing what they should, then get this message on step 3. What am I missing here?

```
administrator@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install perforce-swarm
[sudo] password for administrator: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package perforce-swarm is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'perforce-swarm' has no installation candidate
```

Edit: re-ran `sudo apt-get update` full output below

```
administrator@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for administrator: 
Hit http://package.perforce.com precise InRelease
Hit http://package.perforce.com precise/release i386 Packages                  
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                                
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                              
Ign http://package.perforce.com precise/release Translation-en_US              
Ign http://package.perforce.com precise/release Translation-en                 
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release                           
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease              
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease            
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                      
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                   
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease              
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg [933 B] 
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg [933 B]  
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release.gpg         
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release                       
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release [63.5 kB]     
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release [63.5 kB]           
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release                      
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                           
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources                     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources                       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources                     
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US                     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages               
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                        
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources [80.3 kB]        
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages         
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages            
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en          
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en           
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en             
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources [196 kB]        
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Sources [2,061 B]  
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources [21.9 kB]    
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Sources [1,922 B]  
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages [256 kB]
Get:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources [2,564 B]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources [114 kB]   
Get:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Sources [4,773 B]
Get:14 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages [500 kB] 
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages [8,846 B]
Get:16 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages [101 kB]
Get:17 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages [9,256 B]
Get:18 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages [3,643 B]
Get:19 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages [276 kB]
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en             
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en       
Get:20 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [11.9 kB]
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en         
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en            
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Sources      
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Sources           
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Sources  
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Sources           
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en          
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US                 
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_US 
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_US 
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US   
Fetched 1,718 kB in 16s (106 kB/s)                                             
Reading package lists... Done
administrator@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install perforce-swarm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package perforce-swarm is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'perforce-swarm' has no installation candidate
administrator@ubuntu:~$
```

Edit 2: more infos

```
administrator@ubuntu:~$ ls -l /var/lib/apt/lists/ | grep perforce
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     3168 Apr 22 18:16 package.perforce.com_apt_ubuntu_dists_precise_InRelease
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    15822 Apr 22 18:16 package.perforce.com_apt_ubuntu_dists_precise_release_binary-i386_Packages
```

Comment: add a tag with your Ubuntu version

Comment: [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/618649/edit) your question and add the output of `ls -l /var/lib/apt/lists/ | grep perforce` and give me a comment wit @A.B.

Comment: @A.B. edited question with the additional info

Comment: You have a 32-bit system, right?

Comment: @A.B. that is correct, 32-bit system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had no luck with the package, so I ended up going the long way around and installing/configuring via the distribution a la http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/swarm/setup.dependencies.html